# "Non-function value encountered for default slot." in Vue 3 Composition API component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, slots

MCVE

https://github.com/hyperbotauthor/minvue3cliapp

MCVE live

https://codesandbox.io/s/white-browser-fl7ji

I have a Vue 3 cli-service app, that uses composition API components with slots.

The `HelloWorld` component renders the slots it receives in a `div`:

```js
// src/components/Helloworld.js
import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => h("div", {}, slots);
  }
});
```

The `Composite` component uses `HelloWorld` in its `setup` function and fills in its slots:

```js
// src/components/Composite.js
import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";

import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld";

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () =>
      h(HelloWorld, {}, [h("div", {}, ["Div 1"]), h("div", {}, ["Div 2"])]);
  }
});
```

The app uses both ways to render the same two divs:

```html
<template>
  <!--<img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">-->
  Works with plain slots
  <HelloWorld>
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
  </HelloWorld>
  Triggers warning when slots are used from other component
  <Composite> </Composite>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import Composite from "./components/Composite";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Composite,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The `Composite` component triggers this warning:

```
Non-function value encountered for default slot. Prefer function slots for better performance.
```

The same warning is not triggered when I use `HelloWorld` from only the template.

I don't understand what is the difference if I use the slots from a template or from an other component.

What is the point of this warning?

Is there any way I can remove this warning?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The warning is about the array of `VNode`s created in the `setup()`'s render function in `Composite.js`.

```js
// src/components/Composite.js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () =>
      h(HelloWorld, {}, [h("div", {}, ["Div 1"]), h("div", {}, ["Div 2"])]);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
});
```

This is inefficient because the child slot is rendered *before* the `HelloWorld` component could even use it. The child slot is essentially rendered in the parent, and then passed to the child. Wrapping the child slot generation in a function defers the work until the child is rendered.

> I don't understand what is the difference if I use the slots from a template or from an other component.

`@vue/compiler-sfc` compiles the `<template>` from SFCs into a render function, where slots are passed as functions, which avoids the warning you observed.

### Solution

Instead of rendering the child slot in the parent (i.e., passing an array of `VNodes` as the `slots` argument directly), wrap it in a function:

```js
// src/components/Composite.js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () =>          
      h(HelloWorld, {}, () => [h("div", {}, ["Div 1"]), h("div", {}, ["Div 2"])]);
  }
});
```

Note the inner `h()` calls don't need this function wrapper because they're all rendered together with the default slot *by the child*.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dan-d90xj?file=/src/components/Composite.js)

Answer (score 2):

You can also easily get this error when you pass an empty array to the children argument when constructing nested components.

For example:

```
const children = () => {
  const marker = h(ATreeDefaultMarker, {
    hasChildren: item.children.length > 0,
    isOpen: item.open ?? false,
  }, []); // <--------------------- This

  const indent = h(ATreeDefaultIndent, {
    item,
  }, []); // <--------------------- This

  const display = h(ATreeDefaultItem, { item, events });
  return [indent, marker, display];
};

return () => h(ATreeDefaultLine, children)];
```

Although the top level call to `h` is returning an array of `VNode` to put into the `default` slot, the children are being accidentally rendered with an empty array for the child list:

`h(..., props, [])` <--- like this.

Vue can't distinguish between an empty child array and one that actually has children, so it raises an error like:

```
Vue warn]: Non-function value encountered for default slot. Prefer function slots for better performance. 
 at <ATreeDefaultIndent> 
 at <ATreeDefaultLine>
```

The warning is simply that the child array is not a function, and in this case, it makes no difference.

...however, the linter can't tell that.

##### tldr

If you see this error, it's also worth checking you're not accidentally passing an empty child list like `[]` to `h` accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

correct solution to hide this warning is :

change array children to :

```js
{
  default: () => children,
}
```

for your example it must be change to this :

```js
return () =>
  h(HelloWorld, {}, {
    default: () => [h("div", {}, ["Div 1"]), h("div", {}, ["Div 2"])],
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another fix to the thread if anyone ever encounters something else but similar to this
You may want to use

```
h(YourComponent, () => "some label")
```

Or

```
h(YourComponent, {}, "some label")
```

Instead of this

```
h(YourComponent, "some label") // non-function value enco...
```

This is likely a conditional bug of the render function `h()`, looks silly but it took me an hour to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

A non-function value for `default` slot warning appears to occur when no default slot was available for the custom component. (For example, if you use `resolveComponent` for the first argument of `h`.) In such a case, I assume Vue tries to compensate for the lack of a defined default slot, which itself is technically unnecessary and redundant if the component were completely available. This overhead would be what reduces performance.